# Programming hurts my right pinky. How do I improve my typing to reduce strain on it?

Tags: ergonomics

I've noticed recently that when I program for periods of time, my right pinky starts to hurt a little. I think it has to do with the frequent need to use arrow keys for autocompletion and navigating around the code.

I started using the microsoft ergonomic keyboard and looking into touch typing but the former accentuates the distance of the arrow keys making the problem worse and the latter does not seem to be oriented for people who are constantly using modifier keys and arrow keys.

I read a bunch of suggestions that basically amount to switching over to learning the vim shortcuts and though I have used vim, I just don't see it as convenient, even in the form of ideaVim for my intellij setup as it's quite annoying to keep switching modes. That said, I have liked the way vim uses hjkl as arrows so I'm trying to see if I can adapt to use ctrl + the letter to substitute for arrow keys.

Also I'm not going to learn to use a dvorak keyboard. I already have enough trouble dealing with shortcut differences when I switch between macs and PC. Dvorak is interesting but in the end we live in a qwerty world.

I'd love to hear any solutions you guys have come up with.

Comment: Wear wrist braces preventatively during work.  Forcing your wrists to stay straight while typing can help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace as described in [help]

Comment: is this serious?

Comment: Also be cognizant of where you're resting your elbow - I had a chair where the arm pressed against the nerve on the outside of my elbow, and it resulted in numbness in my pinky strangely enough. Sit straight, position your keyboard properly, and get up and move around every so often.

Comment: Used your pointer, index, and ring finger on the arrow keys, like the WASD form gamers use. Also, learn VIM properly. You never need to touch the mouse or take your hands off the Home Row position for long. `jkl;` are your friends.

Comment: If ergonomics is a valid tag for the workplace (and the OP obviously was able to select it), then it seems like this should be a valid question.

Comment: When I use the right arrow key I use my ring finger,  not pinky. Also see if you adjust autocompletion to use the enter key instead of the arrow key (I'm guessing you're describing choosing the autocompletion item).

Comment: make a conscious effort to use a different finger. I have an issue in my wrist if I use a mouse for a while (too much gaming I think in my youth so probably RSI, I never got it checked out) which is very painful. I now use the mouse in the wrong hand and touch pads and eventually got used to it. Otherwise it would have just got worse and worse. These can become permanent physical problems and people have had to have surgery in extreme cases.

Comment: I had this, I found it was because my pinky was hanging off my mouse. i bought a mouse that looked like [this](http://www.lightinthebox.com/wired-vertical-mouse-ergonomic-design-mice-5-buttons-optical-usb-pc-laptop-computer-optical-mouse-assorted-colors_p3175255.html?currency=GBP&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&sku=429_6917&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&adword_mt=&adword_ct=84187195634&adword_kw=&adword_pos=1o5&adword_pl=&adword_net=g&adword_tar=&adw_src_id=1810908567_301579154_21687113474_pla-78746278147&gclid=CNOj2L6Uk8sCFasEwwodtyIEdw) and it hasn't been sore since!

Comment: If you use auto-completion a lot, I recommend assigning *TAB* to be the hotkey for this action. It feels much better to type.

Comment: @Dogbert when you use vim how do you type brackets? for example, when I do it I usually type '(' ')' then arrow back. if I were to use vim. Then I would have to type 'i' '(' ')' 'esc' 'h' 'i' it seems like a lot of work for something I do frequently. I think there is a vim 'autoclose' feature that closes brackets and '"' marks... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316727/automatic-closing-brackets-for-vim) Do you use one of these?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo Yep, I do find myself jumping between modes like how you described, hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd>. It's not as painful as one would think. Once you've mastered the movement keys (ie: `e` = end of word, ctrl+f/b for pgup/pgdn, etc), you find you're able to jump to an exact position in a page/file/line with a single keystroke. In general, pretend everything to the right of the ENTER key (the arrows, numpad, insert/del/pgup/etc island) doesn't exist.

Comment: I use one of these: http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/advantage-for-pc-mac/ - it's an unusual layout, but it gives you the arrow keys underneath your index and long finger when touch typing, as well as moving the enter and backspace keys to your thumbs. Much easier on the pinkies. I honestly couldn't work as a programmer without one of these.

Comment: I'll say the same thing to you my friend said to me a year ago, ~"are you sure it's the keyboard and not from balancing your large smartphone on your pinky?"
At the time I did not realize he was right.  For me it hurt most when I'd press enter by stretching out my pinky.  Never had issues w/ Galaxy S4 and believe the injury began when I upgraded to an S10e, which is a bit bigger.

Comment: good point on smartphones @AndyP. In my case my problem was about computer keyboards but it's definitely an ergonomic issue on smartphones to watch out for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the ergonomics of your workstation.  Is the monitor the right height?  Is your chair the right height relative to the desk?  Is the keyboard a distance away on the desk that's comfortable *for you*?  Do you need a wrist rest, or *not* need a wrist rest?  Is the keyboard at the right angle?

Other than that, try *not* to touch type.  I can bash away all day with my index and middle fingers with no problems.  Try using the mouse instead of the keyboard.  If using the mouse too much also causes problems, see if the MouseKeys under the ease of access options on your operating system helps.  I regularly use it in a strange way where I move the mouse with my left hand and bash the MouseKey buttons with my right - but that may not work at all for you.

Comment: Hey Simon. Interesting point to avoid touch typing. I'll try it but I was wondering if you had any links that discusses it.

Comment: @ThinkBonobo It looks as though many sites recommend that you *do* learn to touch type http://xahlee.info/kbd/programer_keyboarding_advice.html though describing anything other than touch typing as "hunt and peck" is a bit extreme.  https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/pinky-rsi.html looked interesting, though.  *Don't assume that what works for me works for you.*